# Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain android build error

Tags: cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework, android-build

I have created one APP in ionic. The App was working fine but when I have upgraded my Android studio build is not creating. Below is details for my APP.

ionic 3.0
cordova 6.5.0
node 7.7.2
npm 4.1.2

Recently I upgraded to android studio.3.2.1

Below is the error I am getting when I was running command : "ionic cordova build android"

https://www.screencast.com/t/rWuvP46MIhk

> Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" D:\wamp64\www\COB-App\hooks\
>   after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js D:\wamp64\www\COB-App
>   add to body class: platform-android
>   ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
>   JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73
>   Subproject Path: CordovaLib
>
> Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
>   Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>   Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
>
> cordova build android exited with exit code 1.
>
> Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more
>           information.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.